# How to assert an object containing `Date` properties using chai and deep.equals?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, date, chai

I have an existing typescript code base making use of the the native `Date` object. I want to add a testcases to it, yet when comparing my objects using `deep.equals`, I get a mismatch:

```
  AssertionError: expected { date: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 11:05:03 GMT } to deeply equal { date: '2020-01-20T11:05:03.638Z' }
  + expected - actual

   {
  -  "date": [Date: 2020-01-20T11:05:03.638Z]
  +  "date": "2020-01-20T11:05:03.638Z"
   }
```

Here's my code:

```
it.only("compare the date", async () => {
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 20, 11, 5, 3, 638));
    const actual = {
        date,
    };

    const expected = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(actual));

    expect(actual).to.deep.eq(expected);
});
```

The example is contrived yet in my codebase I basically also load the expected objects from JSON files.

Comment: You're comparing a `Date` object to a *string*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know. I have written both the question and answer since I already figured that out.

Comment: But why did you think this would need a Q&A? Was something unclear from the output that `[Date: ...]` is not the same as `"..."`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe In order to document my solution and in order to maybe save someone else a few minutes. It doesn't get more basic than that. Where do you see the harm in having this Q&A?

Comment: I suppose I don't see that anyone could search for and find this faster than they could just read the test output.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not coming from chai but stems from a limiation of the JSON format. Since you store the expected object in a JSON file, the object loses the `Date` type and is converted to a string.

JSON only supportes these types:

- string
- number
- integer
- boolean
- null

`JSON.stringify` is calling the `toString` method on each object, which is why you get the string in the JSON.

To rectify that you have different options.

- Refactor your code to transform your `Date` properties to either string representation of Date or numeric UNIX timestamps.
- Use the revive function of JSON.parse to get back a date object. (This may lead to unwanted effects as it depends on the name of your properties. Make sure to only convert the date properties you want to convert.)

  ```
  it("compare the date", async () => {
      const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 20, 11, 5, 3, 638));
      const actual = {
          date,
      };

      const reviver = (key, value) => (key === "date") ? new Date(value) : value;
      const expected = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(actual), reviver);

      expect(actual).to.deep.eq(expected);
  });
  ```